# Isolating 'active' parts in signal

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, fft

I have a dataset which contains a signal from buttons pressed. Now in the entire timeperiod the data covers, there is also noise. The data itself is just a vector which contains numbers which correspond to linear combinations of sine functions.

I want to isolate the parts where a button is pressed. So I first thought to use a certain threshold for the noise. The noise is never higher than `0.4`, thus this would be a good threshold. So my plan is to create new vectors, each which contain the data from the timeperiod a single button is pressed, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I reckon I need code that runs over the vector that check whether the threshold of `0.4` is overcome and then stores the data into a new vector until at least `x` many entries are again below the threshold value.

Would this idea work? And I have no clue how to start this check, any help is appreciated.

Just for information: in the end I want to extract the sine functions using `fft`, but without using the `signal processing toolbox`.

***EDIT***

I now created the (partially) working code:

```
z= [0 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.6 0.3 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.3 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.0];
zN = length(z);
y=[;];
m=0;
j=0;
i=1;
while i < zN
    if z(i) >= 0.4
        m=m+1;
        k=0;
        for j = i:zN
            k=k+1;
            y(m,k) = z(j);
            if z(j) <0.4 && z(j+1)<0.4 && z(j+2)<0.4
                i=i+j+3;
                break
            end
        end
    end
i=i+1;    
end
```

This, as hoped, gives back a matrix `y=[0.4 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.6 0.3; 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.3 0 0]`. But, to me, this looks very ugly and is not very readable. Also, I now have manually assigned that the next three entries should be below `0.4`, but I would like to manage this by a variable so I could just as easily assign the logic to be the next thirty entries in stead of just three. Also, this created the right vector, but it does not continue to run over the code and create new vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of the requirements you stated, your loop code gives wrong results, even for the given `z`. Running your code as is for the given `z`, we get:

```
y =
   0.40000   0.20000   0.80000   0.30000   0.60000   0.30000
   0.40000   0.50000   0.60000   0.30000   0.00000   0.00000
```

But, at least from my understanding, the first "active interval" should be:

```
   0.40000   0.20000   0.80000   0.30000   0.60000   0.30000   0.30000   0.20000
```

Here, the requirement to have three successive values below the threshold is fulfilled, which is not the case for your result `y`.

I didn't want to correct your for loop, and since you asked for some different approach as well, below would be my solution. If it's "readable" or "ugly", depends on the reader. I tried to comment every line. Also, you can inspect all intermediate results to further understand the idea and functioning.

```matlab
z = [0.0 0.1 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.6 0.3 0.3 0.2 0.1 ...
     0.2 0.0 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.3 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.0]; 

% Threshold
thr = 0.4;

% Successor threshold
nSucc = 3;

% Find indices, where z >= threshold ("overshoot")
idxOver = find(z >= thr);

% Calculate distances between these overshoots
distOver = diff(idxOver);

% Distances below successor threshold are considered to belong 
% to the same active interval; split active intervals where
% successor threshold is exceeded
idxSplitItv = find(distOver > nSucc);

% Determine starts and ends of the active intervals
idxActiveS = idxOver([1, idxSplitItv+1]);
idxActiveE = idxOver([idxSplitItv, numel(idxOver)]) + nSucc;
nActive = numel(idxActiveS);

% If end of last interval would exceed length of z, ignore
if (idxActiveE(end) > numel(z))
  x = 1:nActive-1;
else
  x = 1:nActive;
end

% Get all active intervals
yy = arrayfun(@(x) z(idxActiveS(x):idxActiveE(x)), x.', 'UniformOutput', false)
```

For the given `z`, we get:

```
yy =
{
  [1,1] =
     0.40000   0.20000   0.80000   0.30000   0.60000   0.30000   0.30000   0.20000

  [2,1] =
     0.40000   0.50000   0.60000   0.30000   0.30000   0.20000
}
```

Since "active intervals" can have varying lengths, I decided to use cell arrays for the output. Notice: `arrayfun` is just some loop in disguise, so looping for the last step would be OK here, too.

If we cut the last three elements from `z`, such that there's no valid second "active interval" (less than three successive values below the threshold), we correctly get:

```
yy =
{
  [1,1] =
     0.40000   0.20000   0.80000   0.30000   0.60000   0.30000   0.30000   0.20000
}
```

On the other hand, if we set `nSucc = 10`, i.e. we need at least ten successive values below the threshold, we get:

```
yy = {}(0x1)
```

That is, because there's no such interval in the given `z`.

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer: I tested the code with Octave 5.1.0, but I'm quite sure, that it should be fully MATLAB-compatible. If not, please leave a comment, and I'll try to fix possible issues.

Comment: thank you! Very nice and helpful code for me. Much appreciated.